# Service worker makes js run twice

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I implemented the service worker from pwabuilder.com and it works just fine

The problem is that the service worker runs even if the browser is online, so every js functions runs twice, one from the service worker and one from my other js files

Should I look if it's an active service worker before I run my js functions or should I somehow make sure that the service worker is not running when the browser is online?

This is the code I run in my main index file

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            //console.log('[PWA Builder] active service worker found, no need to register')
        } else {
            //Register the ServiceWorker
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('pwabuilder-sw.js', {
                scope: './'
            }).then(function (reg) {
                //console.log('Service worker has been registered for scope:' + reg.scope);
            });
        }
```

The pwabuilder-sw.js looks like this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
var indexPage = new Request('');
event.waitUntil(
    fetch(indexPage).then(function (response) {
        return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function (cache) {
            //console.log('[PWA Builder] Cached index page during Install' + response.url);
            return cache.put(indexPage, response);
        });
    }));
});

//If any fetch fails, it will look for the request in the cache and serve it from there first
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
var updateCache = function (request) {
    return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function (cache) {
        return fetch(request).then(function (response) {
            //console.log('[PWA Builder] add page to offline' + response.url);
            return cache.put(request, response);
        });
    });
};

event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request));

event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function (error) {
        //Check to see if you have it in the cache
        //Return response
        //If not in the cache, then return error page
        return caches.open('pwabuilder-offline').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.match(event.request).then(function (matching) {
                var report = !matching || matching.status === 404 ? Promise.reject('no-match') : matching;
                return report;
            });
        });
    })
);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Service Workers are meant to work all the time once registered, installed and activated

*Service workers are event driven and their primary use is to act as a **caching agent**, to **handle network requests** and to **store content** for offline use. Secondly to **handle push messaging**.*

> I trust you understand that in order to act as a caching agent the service worker will run regardless if the application is online or offline. You have various caching scenarios to consider.

It is hard to provide exact solution for the mentioned: 'every js functions runs twice'.
I doubt that all JS functions would always run twice. It seems this is implementation dependant.

> Service workers cannot have a scope above their own path, by default it will control all resources below the scope of the service worker, this scope can also be restricted.

```
navigation.serviceWorker.register(
    '/pwabuilder-sw.js', { //SW located at the root level here
        scope: '/app/' //to control all resource accessed form within path /app/
    }
);
```

I believe that the script from pwabuilder.com does attempt to cache all resources even resources that should not be cached such as POST requests. You may need to modify the caching policy depending on what type of resources your are using.

There is no simple solution here and no easy answer can be provided.

> In general you can use the service worker to cache resources in one of the following ways:

- Cache falling back to network

  ```
  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
      event.responseWith(
          caches.match(event.request)
          .then((response) => {
              return response || fetch(event.request);
          })
      );
  });
  ```
- Network falling back to cache

  ```
  //Good for resources that update frequently
  //Bad for Intermittend and slow connections
  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
      event.responseWith(
          fetch(event.request).catch(() => {
              return caches.match(event.request);
          })
      );
  });
  ```
- Cache then network

  ```
  //Cache then network(1) (send request to cache and network simultaneousely)
  //show cached version first, then update the page when the network data arrives
  var networkDataReceived = false;
  var networkUpdate = fetch('/data.json')
  .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
      networkDataReceived = true;
      updatePage(data);
  });
  //Cache then network(2)
  caches.match('/data.json')
  .then ((response) => {
      return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
      if (!networkDataReceived) {
          updatePage(data);
      }
  }).catch(() => {
      return networkUpdate;
  });
  ```
- Generic fallback

  ```
  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
      event.responseWith(
          caches.match(event.request)
          .then((response) => {
              return response || fetch(event.request);
          }).catch(() => {
              return caches.match('offline.html');
          })
      )
  });
  ```

I hope the above helps at least a little find the exact issue you are facing. 
Cheers and happy codding!

Answer (score 0):

React added this React.strictMode HOC that runs twice certain parts of the application, like class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods.
Check the docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects.

See if you have `<React.StrictMode>` at the top of your `index.js` file and if so, you might want to run a test without it.